# How do I call a function multiple times with different parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11

Fairly new to C++ here. I am trying to figure out if I can optimize my code by not calling the same function multiple times. For example see below:
funcCall is a standalone function so it cannot be removed, all it needs to know is those three paramters..

```
const char *a = "H";
const char *b = "e";
const char *c = "l";
const char *d = "l";
const char *e = "o";
const char *f = "Hi";
funcCall(f,a,b);
funcCall(f,c,d);
funcCall(f,d,e);

void funcCall(const char *one, const char *two, const char *three)
{
//Kindly ignore the syntax
//open the file and write the first two parameters to it
fopen(three.txt);
fwrite(one,two,three.txt); //ignore syntax
fclose(three.txt);
}
```

Comment: Beware that you must not name your variable `const`. That is a reserved keyword with a special meaning.

Comment: I suggest that you learn about arrays and loops.

Comment: Make use of loops and vector of char *

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57188134/edit) your question and show us the implementation of `funcCall()`?

Comment: In addition to the above comments, we can't know how to remove your function calls without knowing what the function does.

Comment: Updated the question, I was using the const just as an example.

Comment: Also I was thinking about using a loop but wasn't sure how to implement it with more than one parameter For example: const char *args[]={a,b,c,d,e,f}

Comment: @John We still can't help without the implementation of `funcCall()` Please still add it.

Comment: Added a basic overview of funcCall, but as I mentioned I intend to keep it a standalone  program which only cares about the three parameters it is passed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of the characters, and loop over it two at a time, like so:

```
char abcdef[] = "Helllo";
const char* hi = "Hi";
for (char* p = abcdef; p < abcdef + 6; p += 2) {
    funcCall(hi, p[0], p[1]);
}
```

This differs from your example in that it passes characters as the second and third arguments to `funcCall`, rather than null-terminated character strings.

After your edit, it looks like the parameters are really supposed to be strings, not just characters, so you'd want to have an array of strings rather than an array of characters.  So you can do something like

```
std::vector<const char*> args = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
std::vector<const char*> files = {"A.txt", "B.txt", "C.dat"};
const char* hi = "Hi";
for (int i = 0; i < std::min(args.size(), files.size()); ++i) {
    funcCall(hi, args[i], files[i]);
}
```

where `funcCall` takes `const char*` arguments as in your example. (It would probably be better to use `std::string`.)